# I have Xdatcar file, taken from AIMD Output using Vasp, How can I write a code in python to store data with time in X column and positions in Y col

Tags: python

I have XDATCAR DATA of 10ps with 2fs time interval. I want to convert in to .dat file using Python code where X column  will be the time and multiple y columns will be the atoms positions.

I just want to draw a atomic trajectory with python code using XDATCAR

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.